# Android Button drawable doesnt show

Tags: android, user-interface, drawable, androiddesignsupport

I want to have a circular button. It show's on the designer as expected but the button itself doesn't show on the actual device when running, nor when i click the position of the button it does absolutely nothing.

Why isn't the button showing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000">




<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/security_calling_disarm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:background="@drawable/security_calling_disarm"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

**Drawable file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#00FF00"/>
    </shape>
```

Comment: constraint of Button is not set correctly, Use the magic wand tool on the design tab of of your layout xml. It will automatically fix this

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO I already did that. Did not help.

Comment: Try using other layout and then check whether it is working or not

Comment: Are you setting the text for the button? Wrap content may cause it to have 0 width if it doesn't have text inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're setting the `layout_width` to `wrap_content` the shape is missing a width to be drawn.

Try changing it to something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/security_calling_disarm"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:background="@drawable/security_calling_disarm"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

This way `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` will make sure the width matches the height.

Answer (score 1):

Please, make sure you added top and end constraints as well. As documentation says, it may shows in incorrect way after running in real device if you haven't set all the constraints.

Comment: I checked that too. I don't think constraint's are the case here.

Comment: @user8222166 I created new project and added this layout file as content view. So, it works and button appears. Do you have something except this button in your layout file, that can overlay it? Or you include this layout file inside some parent layout?